# OpenShift default service accounts create a duplicated secret-token

Tags: namespaces, openshift

For every new namespace OpenShift creates default service accounts with one registry & one api secret referenced.

[image]

But for some reason the namespace has three secrets for each service account, two API-token secrets without the second one being referenced and the registry secret. I compared the two token secrets and besides the actual token variable there is no difference. Is this a normal behavior and if so, why?

[image]